# org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=iso-8859-1,

Tags: java, json, jersey

i'm calling a rest API with java client using jersey, here is my code:

```
    public static ContractInfo getContractInfo(Message message) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException {
    //SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
    //ctx.init(null, null, null);
    //Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder().sslContext(ctx).build();
    SSLContext sslContext = getSslContext();
    HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new NoOpHostnameVerifier();
    //ClientConfig config = new ClientConfig();
    //config.register(JacksonJaxbJsonProvider.class);

    Client client = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
            .sslContext(sslContext)
            .hostnameVerifier(allHostsValid)
            .build();
    WebTarget target=client.target("IP_ADRESS");
    Response restResponse = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(message));
    
    ContractInfo contractInfo = restResponse.readEntity(ContractInfo.class);
    
    return contractInfo;
}
```

and i get the exeption below:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=text/html;charset=iso-8859-1, type=class com.atos.activhttp.model.ContractInfo, genericType=class com.atos.activhttp.model.ContractInfo.
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:208)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor.proceed(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:132)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.readFrom(MessageBodyFactory.java:1072)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:885)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.InboundMessageContext.readEntity(InboundMessageContext.java:819)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.readEntity(ClientResponse.java:298)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse$1.call(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:93)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:205)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:365)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.runInScopeIfPossible(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:244)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.InboundJaxrsResponse.readEntity(InboundJaxrsResponse.java:90)
at com.atos.activhttp.rest.RestConnection.getContractInfo(RestConnection.java:38)
```

the APi was tested with restTemplate and work fine.

Comment: You are getting an HTML page as the response. Why? Who knows. You should view the HTML page to see what it is. My guess is there is some error on the server side and you are getting an HTML error page.

Comment: indeed im getting a HTML page with 404 not found

Comment: the probleme is solved, the cause is that i was calling the API with the IP adress not the domain name.